# How to select several paragraphs using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have som HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>paragraph1</p>                                 
    <p>paragraph2</p>
    <p>paragraph3</p>
    <p>paragraph4</p>
    <p>paragraph5</p>
    <p>paragraph6</p>
</div>
```

JQuery function to select one of the paragraph:

```
$(function() {
    $("#content *").hover( function () {
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid blue");
        return false;
    },
    function () {
        $(this).css("border", "none");  //  unmark the paragraphs
    }).click( function (evtObj) {
         //make action with selected paragraph
        };
    });
});
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rvvbf4L1/6/

How to select by mouse click several paragraphs and get their inner HTML?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? Do you mean for the borders to toggle on click?

Comment: Yes, I mean - to toggle on click.

Comment: Please be more precise about desired behavior... one at a time is trivial...using  keyboard and mouse together for selecting groups is more complex. Also show what you have tried to accomplish this...even if it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `css` with your `jQuery` instead of using the hover. Then add and remove a `selected` class. This would also allow you to do `$('p.seleted').each(function () {})` on the all the paragraphs which may prove useful.

#### Style

```
<style>
p.selected {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

p:hover {
   border: 1px dotted blue; 
}
</style>
```

#### Toggling the class and calling new myClass

```
$("#content *").click( function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var allHtml = ""; 
        $("p.selected").each(function () {
            allHtml += " " + $(this).html(); 
        });
        var inst = new myClass(allHtml);

    }
});
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h6eh1j6/1/)

Comment: can simplify conditional and 3 class method calls down to `toggleClass()`

Comment: @charlietfl `toggleClass` doesn't have a call back to run the `new myClass`

Comment: just a suggestion was all

Comment: It looks very nice, but how can I get the content of all selected paragraphs?

Comment: I have updated my answer to use the `$.each` function as suggested earlier.

Comment: Super. I understood. Many thanx.

Answer (score -1):

I did a quick test by pasting your html into a blank text file. If you do not include a jQuery library, you don't get multiple results. Try your jQuery code with the following html:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <p>paragraph1</p>                                 
    <p>paragraph2</p>
    <p>paragraph3</p>
    <p>paragraph4</p>
    <p>paragraph5</p>
    <p>paragraph6</p>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```